# Alfresco 7.4 old aikau extension not working

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, aikau

I have my own add-on in Alfresco version 5.2 (SDK 2.2.0) which use aikau 1.0.101. I wanna use it in my project with Alfresco 7.4. When i tried upload my AMP into 7.4 (aikau 1.0.127), Alfresco working well but all my extension in aikau are not shown or are not clickable. In logs is only this one error:

```
ERROR [extensions.surf.DependencyAggregator] [http-nio-8080-exec-7] Could not find compressed file: js/com/acme/pages/services/MyService.js
```

I was searching about some information about aikau versions and compatibility but not found any. How to properly use old aikau extension in new version of Alfresco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to upgrade whole old add-on from SDK 2.2 to SDK 4.6 and it works! I was scary how complicated it will be but i did in couple of hours.

I created new AIO project from mvn archetype (used same groupId and artifactId from old one). Then put all my extension files into and fix some paths. Most tricky part at the end was move js files from:

```
/old-share-5.0/src/main/amp/web/js/com/acme/project
```

to:

```
/new-share-7.3/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/new-share-7.3/js
```

ant then fix package location in
`/new-share-7.3/src/main/resources/alfresco/web-extension/site-data/extensions/project-extension.xml`